# Knockout append observables w/ characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have observables in my KnockoutJS app and their values are being fetched from an array that's contained globally in the app, eg:

```
self.observable = ko.observable(App[0].Observable_Value);
```

For ease, let's say Observable_Value = 10.

This is working as you'd expect it to and the `<input>` that self.observable is binded to has the correct value in it by default; 10.

What I want to do now is to append the observable with a **%** in the `<input>` so the displayed output in the input field will be 10%.

I simply want to append the input value with a **%** because I need the observable to be readable as a number and *not* a string to prevent NaN errors later on in the app. The app relies heavily on numbers.

I've tried doing this as a computed function with read/write & parseFloat but to no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best option in this case would be a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

> I simply want to append the input value with a % because I need the observable to be readable as a number and not a string

That is precisely what a binding handler could do - preserve the original value of the observable, but change the way that it is displayed.

> I've tried doing this as a computed function

Although a computed function could do the trick, it's usually unecessary unless you want to actually work with the return value from the computed. In this case, since you just want to change the visual display, you don't need a another variable representing the same value.

Here is a **very** basic one that just puts a `%` sign in front of the observable's value. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h36ma/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.percent = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).text('%' + value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah I just whipped up a similar thing before you posted the fiddle, thanks so much! I'm still a newb to Knockout!

Comment: Eurgh, just encountered a new error. As soon as you go in and update the value with a %, the total that's displayed on the page becomes NaN because the % is interfering!

Comment: @leaksterrr could you make a fiddle (or modify mine) to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a read/write computable that will add the percent for display, then remove it when setting the underlying value [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/nZq27/2/):

```
ko.observable.fn.formatAsPercent = function() {
    var base = this;
    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return base() + "%";
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            base(parseInt(newValue.replace('%', '')));
        }
    });
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.number = ko.observable(10); // actual number
    self.percent= self.number.formatAsPercent(); // used for binding to show %
}

var my = { vm : new ViewModel() };

ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```